# Meteor before login hook to change login query

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am building a multi-domain website. so the users in a particular domain should not access from the another domain. I would like to add a field in login query. Is there hook or function before `login` or `onlogin` ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [validateLoginAttempt](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsServer-validateLoginAttempt) can help you.

You can update your user.profile with an status or domain field for instance:

```
Meteor.users.update({ _id: id }, { $set: {'profile.status': 'deleted'} });
```

And you can check that on server before allow the user login:

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(options) {  
  if(options.user.profile.status &&
    options.user.profile.status === 'deleted'){
    throw new Meteor.Error('Not allowed');
  }

  return true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built in *before* login hook that you could use to block access directly (but there is an [after](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsCommon-onLogin)). Assuming your multiple domains share a user collection then you have a few options:

1. Fork Meteor's accounts package to implement your own rules
2. In your login UI, watch for changes in the username/email field and run a check via a server method to see if that user is logging into the correct domain.
3. If they login to the *wrong* domain, automatically redirect them to the right domain. They'll already be logged in which is nice.

Comment: Thanks Michel, forked meteor account packages to local and implemented my rules. Thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

I think we have onBefore and onAfter action to identify if the user is login or not.so you can mention your login page in onBefore action after that all pages are in onAfter action